# Review totals in mouseover are lumped together

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Incorrect count of completed reviews on /review screen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152202/incorrect-count-of-completed-reviews-on-review-screen)

In the new Review, when you mouseover a reviewer's avatar, it shows their totals for using that particular Review facet (low quality, edits, or close votes) on that site for the day, week, month, and overall total.

It reports the daily count properly, but it lumps the users remaining reviews from that particular tool together and reports that value for each of the week, the month, and the total count.

I have been able to replicate this for the low quality, suggested edits, and close votes facets on SO, MSO, SU, and Cross Validated.

It's not a pressing, high-priority problem, obviously, but I think it bears mentioning.

[image]