# Stats in /review show wrong count

Tags: bug, review, review-stats

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Review totals in mouseover are lumped together](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146728/review-totals-in-mouseover-are-lumped-together)

Review counts in /review page shows wrong total.

e.g. Take an example of mine.

[image]

Here you can see my total count is 1354, month's count is also 1354 and week's count is also 1354 which is wrong.

Proof:
[I have already earned a gold badge (Steward) for *Low Quality Post* for more than 2 weeks ago](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/2279/steward?userid=1369235). (When the badge was created.)

So obviously at least week count is wrong.