# Review stats are showing wrong count again

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review, review-stats

In the review page, it shows stats of recent reviewers. But it is showing wrong stats. Because today (on Monday) it shows week count 53 (on Meta Stack Overflow) which is impossible as there is a limit of 20 reviews per day.

[image]

PS: This bug [has been reported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149710/187824) [many times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146728/187824) and [it was solved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152202/187824). But the bug has occurred again.

Comment: I would query the definition of a week - Is it from Monday,or a rolling week?

Comment: @SeanCheshire - Week means this week, month means this month same as today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL date math is always a joy... Currently this is how those numbers are calculated:

- **Day:** reviews since 0:00 UTC
- **Week:** reviews since 7 days prior to 0:00 UTC
- **Month:** reviews since 30 days prior to 0:00 UTC

This implies two things:

1. week and month are rolling windows, while day is not
2. week and month will usually cover *slightly more* than 7 and 30 days respectively

This doesn't matter if you're just trying to do a quick comparison between two reviewers, and it leaves the numbers immune from the vagaries of the daily cap since it still pins the window to 0:00 UTC - so I'm calling this by-design, but admitting that I'm open to requests to change it.