# Total number of 'reviews today' is wrong

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

Very funny: on the stats page for 'suggested edits', it says there is 1 user with 1 review so far today. However, the counter for 'reviews today' says there are 11. Similar issues exist in other review queues of other Stack Exchange sites, e.g. for first posts. [Here is another example](https://superuser.com/review/first-posts/stats). Checkout these stats to see it at work.

I would not be surprised if the counter has not been reset last night at the start of a new day ... smells like a bug (or yet another undocumented feature ...).

Comment: Reproduced on SFF https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/stats

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was accidentally introduced [while improving the performance of the stats page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322183/review-spring-cleaning-performance-improvements-and-responsive-design) - Today stats are [supposed to be fixed at 0:00 UTC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166143/review-stats-are-showing-wrong-count-again/322190#322190), but the old expression for determining this was something like 50x slower than it needed to be.

The initial fix for that turned the stat into a rolling window, which has its advantages but makes it harder to compare; as of the next build we'll have restored the previous behavior while preserving the speed improvements.

Sorry for the confusion, and thank you for reporting this!

Comment: Compliant to best practises, and with my DevOps background, I can confirm this issue is indeed fixed again to how these stats used to work, merci! BTW, is it appropriate to ask questions on meta.SE about DevOps topics applied to SE sites?

Answer (score 3):

It's slightly different: the column on the left, which shows today's top reviewers, is reset at 12am UTC (as it was before). The big number in the top now shows the number of reviews in the **last 24 hours**. For example, this is the current situation for the Reopen Votes review queue here on Meta: five reviewers today, each with one review, the other five happened yesterday but less than 24 hours ago.

[image] [image]

Comment: Then that label needs adjustment ....

Comment: Yes; I do think the # of reviews in 24 hours is more useful than what it was. (The today top reviewer list is fine as it is.)