# Incorrect count of completed reviews on /review screen

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, review-stats

I'm seeing some behaviour, which I believe is a bug, but wouldn't mind to be corrected.

I navigate to `/review`, then into one of the queues (e.g. "close questions") and review a number of items in that queue.  Then I go back to the `/review` page.  Next to each queue are shown the icons for the last six reviewers.  When I mouse-over the corresponding icon, I get some more details about that reviewer: display name, reputation and the number of completed reviews (day, week, month, total).

Now, this is where I think the values are incorrect.  The count of reviews for the day is correct, however the other ones are not.  I'm pretty sure that I have been doing reviews for more than a week, however my total for the week is shown the same as the total for the month and the same as the overall total.  Note that overall total is correct.

Hence, the bug seems to affect only "reviews this week" and "reviews this month" numbers.  This is the case for all review queue.  See the screenshot below for an example.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct - there was a bug in the query that pulls these stats.  It has been fixed and will go out with the next build.